# Draft.js Cannot convert undefined or null to object convertFromRaw

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-editor, draftjs

I save my html code to sql database as json format

```
const content = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
const raw = JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(content))
```

raw is

> {"entityMap":{},"blocks":[{"key":"4bk88","text":"ridee","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}]}

however when I send it with XMLHTTPRequest in the server it changes req.body become to

```
post.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

This is how it saves

> {"{\"entityMap\":{},\"blocks\":[{\"key\":\"Some Text\",\"text\":\"ridee\",\"type\":\"unstyled\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":":[""]}

so after I recieve it does not return as the expected object

```
const raw = JSON.parse(req.response.htmlcode)
const contentState = convertFromRaw(raw);
```

> {"entityMap":{},"blocks":[{"key":"Some Text","text":"ridee","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":
>   :

I get this as expected however convertFromRaw gives this error

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>
> Object.keys(entityMap).forEach(function (storageKey)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was sending in a wrong format to my server
I have changed
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
to
application/json